# How to rip open an n-gon (circle) and lift one vertex out of the plane

Tags: modeling

I'd like to rip open an n-gon (circle) and lift one or more vertices out of the plane using proportional editing, to create one revolution in a spiral. An easy way to do this would be to delete an edge, then lift an unattached vertex out of the plane, but is there a way to do this without deleting an edge? I tried hiding an edge, but that didn't work. Tks!

Comment: Select one vert then hit the v button.

Comment: Thank you. After I hit v, I can move the vertex, but I'm having trouble controlling where it goes. After hitting v, how can I move the vertex in question, say, 1 BU in the global Z direction, while adjusting the influence radius for proportional editing?

Comment: OK. I got it to work. I needed to change the perspective. Thank you!